# UIKeyboard with other Characters (Hebrew or Russian)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to get an UIKeyboard with a specific characterset for different countries over the iPhone SDK?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the UIKeyboard supports all the installed languages on the device (settings->Keyboard->International)